# How to pass published values between view models?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to pass on a published value from one view model to another (i.e. child view model need access to source and be able to manipulate value). I bet it is simple, however, I can't seem to find the "correct" way of doing within the MVVM pattern.

I've tried using `@Bindings`, `Binding<Value>`. I managed to get it work with `@EnvironmentObject`, but that means the view has to handle it because I can't pass it on to view model where the logic should be (ultimately I want to manipulate the data stream in the child view model using Combine). What have I missed?

I have simplified the situation with the following playground code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class InitialViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPerson: Person = Person(firstName: "", surname: "")
}

struct InitialView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = InitialViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ButtonView(selectedPerson: Published(wrappedValue: viewModel.selectedPerson) )

        SelectedPersonView(selectedPerson: Published(wrappedValue: viewModel.selectedPerson))
    }
}

class ButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPerson: Person

    init(selectedPerson: Published<Person>) {
        self._selectedPerson = selectedPerson
    }

    func toggleSelectedPerson() {
        if selectedPerson.firstName.isEmpty {
            selectedPerson = Person(firstName: "Boris", surname: "Johnson")
        } else {
            selectedPerson = Person(firstName: "", surname: "")
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ButtonViewModel

    init(selectedPerson: Published<Person>) {
        self._viewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: ButtonViewModel(selectedPerson: selectedPerson))
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { viewModel.toggleSelectedPerson()} ) {
            Text("Press to select person")
        }
    }
}

class SelectedPersonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPerson: Person

    init(selectedPerson: Published<Person>) {
        self._selectedPerson = selectedPerson
    }
}

struct SelectedPersonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SelectedPersonViewModel

    init(selectedPerson: Published<Person>) {
        self._viewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: SelectedPersonViewModel(selectedPerson: selectedPerson))
    }

    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.selectedPerson.firstName.isEmpty {
            Text("No person selected yet")
        } else {
            Text("Person \(viewModel.selectedPerson.firstName) selected!")
        }
    }
}

struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let surname: String
}

let view = InitialView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

In essence, when I press the button, the `selectedPerson` property should be updated and the view should update accordingly.

**EDIT 19th August**

Ok, in order to clarify the issue, I've added a very simplified version of the actual code I'm working on. Hopefully this explains as to why I'm looking at this problem.

NOTE: I'm aware of the compiling errors. This is just to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

```
struct ItemOption: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var dependentOn: [Int]? // dependencies where, choosing one option opens up more options
    let values: [ItemOptionValue]
}

struct ItemOptionValue: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String?
}

class OptionViewModel: ObservableObject { // all options e.g. config options on a car
    @Published var selectedOptions = [Int:[Int]]() // Structure of [OptionID: [ValueID]
    @Published var allOptions = [ItemOption]()
    @Published var filteredOptions = [ItemOption]()
    
    init(options: [ItemOption]) {
        self.allOptions = options
        filterAvailableOptions()
    }
    
    func filterAvailableOptions() {
        // Combine code to filter viewable options depending on dependencies that may appear in selectedOption
    }
}

struct OptionView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: OptionViewModel
    
    init(options: [ItemOption]) {
        self.viewModel = OptionViewModel(options: options)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.filteredOptions) { section in
            OptionTypeView(selectedOptions: viewModel.selectedOptions, optionValues: section.values)
        }
    }
}

class OptionTypeViewModel: ObservableObject { // each option type e.g. colour on car, wheel trims etc
    
}

struct OptionTypeView: View {
    var selectedOptions: [Int:[Int]]
    var optionValues: [ItemOptionValue]
    @StateObject var viewModel = OptionTypeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(optionValues) { value in
            OptionValueView(selectedOptions: selectedOptions)
        }
    }
}

class OptionValueViewModel: ObservableObject { // values of each option e.g. each colour choice
    @Published var isOptionSelected: Bool
    @Published var selectedOptions: [Int:[Int]] // passed on value (Binding?) from OptionViewModel
    
    init(selectedOptions: [Int:[Int]]) {
        self.selectedOptions = selectedOptions
    }
    
    func trackSelectedOptions(optionID: Int, valueID: Int) {
        $selectedOptions
        // ... Combine mapping to check if value exists in selectedOptions that originally comes from OptionViewModel
            .assign(\.isOptionSelected, on: self)
    }
    
    func removeOption() {
        // code to remove value id from selectedOptions
    }
    
    func addOption() {
        // code to add value id to selectedOptions
    }
}

struct OptionValueView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: OptionValueViewModel
    
    init(selectedOptions: [Int: [Int]]) {
        self.viewModel = OptionValueViewModel(selectedOptions: selectedOptions)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.isOptionSelected {
            Text("Option is selected")
            Button(action: { viewModel.removeOption } ) {
                Text("Remove option")
            }
        } else {
            Text("Option is NOT selected")
            Button(action: { viewModel.addOption } ) {
                Text("Add option")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One option would be to perhaps join it all together in one massive view (with view model) and func/computed variables handling the sub views in order to have access to the original value, but the problem remains that OptionValueView still needs to calculate it's own value in order to drive what's shown on the view, and this needs to be done in its own view model.

Comment: Is this approximately as complex as your actual project?

Comment: Not at all, but the basic concept remains the same. In the actual project the child view needs access to parent view value (dictionary in this case) in order to subscribe and manipulate the date flow into a simplified dynamic value (Int) in the child view model that the child view needs.

Comment: I'm asking because you'd never do three different view models that simply share one person. This would all be done inside one view model that you share among your views with `environmentObject`. If the child view only needs access to some value, then simply pass that value as `Binding` if you need it or the whole view model as `environmentObject`, don't create a new one.

Comment: Doing this `self._viewModel = ObservedObject` will cause memory leaks and cause your model to re-initialize whenever SwiftUI decides it needs to reload the `View`. I suggest you rethink your approach. You are creating a knot that will only cause more issues as your app grows. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: https://medium.com/@smalam119/viper-design-pattern-for-ios-application-development-7a9703902af6

Comment: @Schottky Thanks for the comments! I've updated the question with a simplified version of the actual code I'm working on so hopefully it makes my dilemma much clearer. I'm praying for a simple solution that I have overlooked or forgotten. Passing values with `Binding` (or using `environmentObject`) to views is not an issue, but then passing it on into the view models cleanly for handling it, seems much harder.

Comment: @loremipsum You are right about the memory leak issue. I appreciate the links you have provided, however, they are not relevant to this as I'm working with MVVM and need to stick to it. I have added new code to my question which perhaps explains better what I am looking for.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. It won’t work as you expect passing the published as you are does not link one with the other as you are expecting. You need a centralized “storage” location for your person and the alternatives that multiple view models can access.

Comment: @loremipsum Ok, makes sense. Thanks. Could I do that without creating a singleton or shared instance? I don't want it shared throughout the whole app and it needs to be deallocated when the options view is no longer required.

Comment: Of course, it depends on where your ultimate source of truth is. A database? A file? A website? the view model will access your manager/store for the data. It doesn’t have to be a singleton. Ultimately there should only be one source of truth and that is your storage.

Comment: @loremipsum The source of truth would be in this case the OptionViewModel.selectedOptions value as once the options are selected and the OptionView dismissed, the selectedOptions needs to be passed back to the server. Perhaps the ViewModelFactory mentioned in https://mokacoding.com/blog/swiftui-dependency-injection/ could work? Seems a tad overkill through, but maybe that's what is needed?

Comment: A view model isn’t a source of truth. When the app restarts all the info is gone. Look [at this](https://www.wintellect.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained/) the source of truth is the Service. The ViewModel is just the middle man. You are missing the service and the ultimate source of truth. In a properly setup app any view model can reference the service/manager/store and get the same data as all the view models

Comment: @loremipsum Ok, sorry, maybe I'm using source of truth wrong. In this case OptionView's only function is to get the options from the user. It is injected with the ItemOptions available, and what we want back is the selected option values from the user so these can be sent back to the server (another example is toppings, bases, sides for a pizza). So we only want the "storage" during the time the options are shown to the user.

Comment: The options as described should be in the Model/Domain look at the article. If the options are people such as in your first example they would come from the service. You could also have a pizza service that connects to the database, what if you add toppings or remove because of shortage? Do you want to resubmit to the app to the App Store if you are out of pepper?

Comment: Sure, I understand. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

After coming across https://mokacoding.com/blog/swiftui-dependency-injection/, I think I've found a solution that works decently well, using a `ViewModelFactory` which creates the view models and directly injects the `PersonController` which is only created once. I could potentially even potentially create the `ViewModelFactory` in the `InitialView` as an `EnvironmentObject` and pass it on down the line to grandchild views if view models are needed to be created further down the line.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let surname: String
}

class PersonController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPerson: Person = Person(firstName: "", surname: "")
}

class ViewModelFactory {
    let personController = PersonController()
    
    func makeButtonViewModel() -> ButtonViewModel {
        return ButtonViewModel(personController: personController)
    }
    
    func makeSelectedPersonViewModel() -> SelectedPersonViewModel {
        return SelectedPersonViewModel(personController: personController)
    }
}

class InitialViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let viewModelFactory = ViewModelFactory()
}

struct InitialView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = InitialViewModel()
    

    var body: some View {
        ButtonView(viewModel: viewModel.viewModelFactory.makeButtonViewModel())

        SelectedPersonView(viewModel: viewModel.viewModelFactory.makeSelectedPersonViewModel())
    }
}

class ButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let personController: PersonController

    init(personController: PersonController) {
        self.personController = personController
    }

    func toggleSelectedPerson() {
        if personController.selectedPerson.firstName.isEmpty {
            personController.selectedPerson = Person(firstName: "Boris", surname: "Johnson")
        } else {
            personController.selectedPerson = Person(firstName: "", surname: "")
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ButtonViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { viewModel.toggleSelectedPerson()} ) {
            Text("Press to select person")
        }
    }
}

class SelectedPersonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPerson: Person
    
    private let personController: PersonController
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(personController: PersonController) {
        self.personController = personController
        
        selectedPerson = personController.selectedPerson
        
        personController.$selectedPerson
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.selectedPerson = $0
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct SelectedPersonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SelectedPersonViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.selectedPerson.firstName.isEmpty {
            Text("No person selected yet")
        } else {
            Text("Person \(viewModel.selectedPerson.firstName) selected!")
        }
    }
}

let view = InitialView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Comment: I am in a similar position but unable to figure out what's wrong. Care to lend me a hand? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095653/how-to-pass-a-parent-viewmodel-published-property-to-a-child-viewmodel-binding

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I can take a look earliest this weekend. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather do somthing like this

```
ButtonView(selectedPerson: viewModel._selectedPerson) )
SelectedPersonView(selectedPerson: viewModel._selectedPerson)
```

I have doubt wheter above will really propagae values from child to parent @Published

BUT:

You can just relay on closure passed to child view model, and this closure via its argument will propaget this events to parent viewmodel and set @Published

```
final class ChildViewModel { 

   init(onSelectedPerson: (Person) -> Void) { }

}
```

or use

> PassthroughSubject

that you pass to child view.