# How to pass a parent ViewModel @Published property to a child ViewModel @Binding using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I'm using an approach similar to the one described on [mockacoding - Dependency Injection in SwiftUI](https://mokacoding.com/blog/swiftui-dependency-injection/) where my main ViewModel has the responsibility to create child viewModels.

In the code below I am **not** including the Factory, as it's very similar to the contents of the post above: it creates the `ParentViewModel`, passes to it dependencies and closures that construct the child view models.

```swift
struct Book { ... }    // It's a struct, not a class

struct ParentView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel: ParentViewModel

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      if viewModel.book.bookmarked { 
        BookmarkedView(viewModel: viewModel.makeBookMarkedViewModel())
      } else {
        RegularView(viewModel: viewModel.makeBookMarkedViewModel())
      }
    }
  }
}


class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var book: Book

  
  // THIS HERE - This is how I am passing the @Published to @Binding
  // Problem is I don't know if this is correct.
  //
  // Before, I was not using @Binding at all. All where @Published
  // and I just pass the reference. But doing that would cause for
  // the UI to NEVER update. That's why I changed it to use @Binding

  private var boundBook: Binding<Book> {
    Binding(get: { self.book }, set: { self.book = $0 })
  }

  // The Factory object passes down these closures
  private let createBookmarkedVM: (_ book: Binding<Book>) -> BookmarkedViewModel
  private let createRegularVM: (_ book: Binding<Book>) -> RegularViewModel
  
  
  init(...) {...}

  func makeBookmarkedViewModel() {
    createBookmarkedVM(boundBook)
  }
}

class BookmarkedView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel: BookmarkedViewModel

  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(book.title)        // <---- THIS IS THE PROBLEM. Not being updated

      Button("Remove bookmark") {
        viewModel.removeBookmark()
      }
    }
    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
      print("adding letter")    // <-- this gets called

      withAnimation {
        viewModel.addLetterToBookTitle()
      }
    }
  }
}

class BookmarkedViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Binding var book: Book

  // ... some other dependencies passed by the Factory object
  init(...) { ... }

  public func removeBookmark() {
    // I know a class would be better than a struct, bear with me


    book = Book(title: book.title, bookmarked: false)
  }

  /// Adds an "a" to the title
  public func addLetterToBookTitle() {
    book = Book(title: book.title + "a", bookmarked: book.bookmarked)

    print("letter added")      // <-- this gets called as well
  }
}
```

From the code above, let's take a look at `BookmarkedView`. If I click the button and `viewModel.removeBookmark()` gets called, the struct is re-assigned and `ParentView` now renders `RegularView`.

This tells me that I successfully bound `@Published book: Book` from `ParentViewModel` to `@Binding book: Book` from `BookmarkedViewModel`, through its `boundBook` computed property. This felt like the most weird thing I had to make.

However, the problem is that even though `addLetterToBookTitle()` is also re-assigning the book with a new title, and it should update the `Text(book.title)`, it's not happening. The same title is being displayed.

I can guarantee that the book title has change (because of some other components of the app I'm omitting for simplicity), but the title's visual is not being updated.

This is the first time I'm trying out these pattern of having a view model build child view models, so I appreciate I may be missing something fundamental. What am I missing?

#### EDIT:

I made an MVP example here: https://github.com/christopher-francisco/TestMVVM/tree/main/MVVMTest.xcodeproj

I'm looking for whether:

- My take at child viewmodels is fundamentally wrong and I should start from scratch, or
- I have misunderstood @Binding and @Published attributes, or
- Anything really

Comment: It’s incorrect Binding inherits Dynamic property that needs a body to get an updated value. In short it will only work inside a SwiftUI View https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

Comment: You have to wrap all ObservableObjects in one of the appropriate wrappers or use .sink call objectWillChange.send()

Comment: Could you help with an example of what should I change?

Comment: I would get rid of the Second ViewModel put all those methods in Book as mutating functions, then just pass the book to the child view. Also, you can pass the first one as an EnvironmentObject.

Comment: There is way too much missing from your code to help any more. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I’ll add a simple MVP example, give me a few hours

Comment: Edited my post with a working MVP

Comment: You are not new in SO, the code should be included in the question, links break over time. `@Binding` does not work in a `class` you still have those in your code. Your approach is fundamentally wrong because of that.

Comment: I understand. The approach is fundamentally wrong then. I'm trying to have a View and Child Views, and have ViewModels for each of them, and that's the problem. Should I instead have a single ViewModel in the parent, and pass it down to the child views ?

Comment: I posted an answer below that makes your code work. You can see the concept there.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said initially `@Binding` does not work in a class you have to use `.sink` to see the changes to an `ObservableObject`.

See below...

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var timer = YourTimer()
    
    let store: Store
    let nManager: NotificationManager
    let wManager: WatchConnectionManager
    
    private let makeNotYetStartedViewModelClosure: (_ parentVM: MainViewModel) -> NotYetStartedViewModel
    private let makeStartedViewModelClosure: (_ parentVM: MainViewModel) -> StartedViewModel
    
    init(
        store: Store,
        nManager: NotificationManager,
        wManager: WatchConnectionManager,
        
        makeNotYetStartedViewModel: @escaping (_ patentVM: MainViewModel) -> NotYetStartedViewModel,
        makeStartedViewModel: @escaping (_ patentVM: MainViewModel) -> StartedViewModel
    ) {
        self.store = store
        self.nManager = nManager
        self.wManager = wManager
        
        self.makeNotYetStartedViewModelClosure = makeNotYetStartedViewModel
        self.makeStartedViewModelClosure = makeStartedViewModel
    }
    
}

// MARK: - child View Models
extension MainViewModel {
    
    func makeNotYetStartedViewModel() -> NotYetStartedViewModel {
        self.makeNotYetStartedViewModelClosure(self)
    }
    
    func makeStartedViewModel() -> StartedViewModel {
        self.makeStartedViewModelClosure(self)
    }
}
class NotYetStartedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var parentVM: MainViewModel
    
    var timer: YourTimer{
        get{
            parentVM.timer
        }
        set{
            parentVM.timer = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    init(parentVM: MainViewModel) {
        self.parentVM = parentVM
        //Subscribe to the parent
        cancellable = parentVM.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { [self] _ in
            //Trigger reload
            objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
    
    func start() {
        // I'll make this into a class later on
        timer = YourTimer(remainingSeconds: timer.remainingSeconds, started: true)
    }
}
class StartedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var parentVM: MainViewModel
    var timer: YourTimer{
        get{
            parentVM.timer
        }
        set{
            parentVM.timer = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init(parentVM: MainViewModel) {
        self.parentVM = parentVM
        cancellable = parentVM.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { [self] _ in
            //trigger reload
            objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
    
    func tick() {
        // I'll make this into a class later on
        timer = YourTimer(remainingSeconds: timer.remainingSeconds - 1, started: timer.started)
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        timer = YourTimer()
    }
}
```

But this is an overcomplicated setup, stick to `class` or `struct`. Also, maintain a single source of truth. That is basically the center of how SwiftUI works everything should be getting its value from a single source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097285/swiftui-combine-issue-sharing-data-between-viewmodels-via-appeventsmanager/77097624#77097624