# SwiftUI Combine Issue: Sharing Data between ViewModels via AppEventsManager

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm facing an issue with SwiftUI and the Combine framework while trying to share data between two ViewModels using the AppEventsManager as a central data store. Here's a simplified representation of my code:

```
    class AppEventsManager {
    static let shared = AppEventsManager()
    var userId = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    init() {
        print("AppEventsManager Init")
    }
}

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String = "123456"
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @StateObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel = FirstViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            Text("New View")
        } label: {
            Text("Go To Another View")
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(
            TapGesture().onEnded {
                AppEventsManager.shared.userId.send("\(firstVM.userId)")
            }
        )
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @StateObject var secondVM: SecondViewModel = SecondViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String = ""
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        print("Text")
        AppEventsManager.shared.userId
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] userId in
                self?.userId = userId
                print("New userId: \(userId)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The issue is that the data is not being shared as expected between the FirstViewModel and SecondViewModel through AppEventsManager. Can someone please help me identify what's going wrong and suggest a solution? Thanks!

Comment: ViewModels should never speak or know about each other you can give the ViewModels access to the same instance of the Manager.

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: Share the same instance of the manager with the 2 view models

Comment: You're using a [PassthroughSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject), which does not replay the previous value upon a new subscription. If `userId` were a [CurrentValueSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject), then `SecondViewModel` would be able to get the previous value of `userId`.

Comment: Just learn the View struct and use SwiftUI as designed and forget about legacy view model objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM ViewModels shouldn't know about each other and communication usually flows

```
View <> ViewModel <> Manager <> Service
```

So Views should never know about managers either.

You can achieve this in your app with a few changes.

First ***Shared Source of Truth***

```
class AppEventsManager {
    static let shared = AppEventsManager()
    @Published var userId = "123456" //Change the Manager so it is now a source of truth
    private init() {
        print("AppEventsManager Init")
    }
}
```

Then change your ViewModels just a little.

```
class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String = ""{
        didSet {
            manager.userId = userId //Let manager know there is a change from the VM not the View.
        }
    }
    private let manager: AppEventsManager
    
    init() {
        print("Text")
        manager = AppEventsManager.shared
        manager.$userId
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$userId)

    }
}
class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String = ""{
        didSet {
            manager.userId = userId //Let manager know there is a change from the VM not the View.
        }
    }
    private let manager: AppEventsManager
    
    init() {
        print("Text")
        manager = AppEventsManager.shared
        manager.$userId
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$userId)

    }
}
```

It is important to know that SwiftUI should only be used in the "Presentation Layer" which is made of the "View <> ViewModel".

Now your Views can be completely un related and still have the same info.

```
struct SampleSharedManagerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            List {
                Section("first") {
                    FirstView()
                }
                Section("second") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @StateObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel = FirstViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(firstVM.userId) {
            Text(firstVM.userId)
                .task {
                    firstVM.userId = UUID().uuidString

                }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @StateObject var secondVM: SecondViewModel = SecondViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World! \(secondVM.userId)")
    }
}
```

**EXTRA**

The above example automatically updates the manager when the ViewModel's userId changes (every key, every tap, etc.).

The benefit/purpose of ViewModels is to remove logic/work from the Views so that logic can be shared with other Views.

A common use case is "verification" such as the verification of a password, etc. A ViewModel allows you share changes once they are final.

```
class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //Does not automatically update manager.
    @Published var userId: String = ""
    private let manager: AppEventsManager
    
    init() {
        print("Text")
        manager = AppEventsManager.shared
        manager.$userId
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$userId)

    }
    
    func verifyUserId() {
        //Perform verification
        
        //Then tell the manager
        manager.userId = userId
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @StateObject var secondVM: SecondViewModel = SecondViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("userId", text: $secondVM.userId)
            Button("Verify") {
                secondVM.verifyUserId()
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why this doesn't work with NavigationLink?

Comment: @LukaŠalipur the issue with your `NavigationLink` is the `simultaneousGesture` that is a bad solution. You an achieve the same thing with `.task` or `onAppear` (I have updated the `FirstView` with a sample) but there are other approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation/75195864#75195864)

Comment: This work, thank you! I'm wondering why was I unable to do this with `PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()`, since base code contain that flow...