# Property binding for classes in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, binding

I need to make binding between properties of view models. There is some prototype of my case. What I am trying to do is to bind property `Coordinaor.isFeatureOn` to `ToggleViewModell.isOn` property. However changes on `Coordinaor.isFeatureOn` is not reflected on `ToggleViewModell.isOn`. Injecting `Coordinator` as `@ObserverObject` into ToggleViewModell is not an option. I thought about `Binding<Bool>` but it does not seem to work with clasees. Please advise appropriate solution

```
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isFeatureOn: Bool = false
    
    func someMethod() {
        let model = ToggleViewModell(state: isFeatureOn, toggleAction: { [weak self] state in
            
            guard let self else { return }
            
            // some service checks if user can turn the feature on
            let isFeatureAvailable = self.ifFeatureAvailable()
            
            // changing @Published is not reflected on ToggleViewModel.isOn property
            isFeatureOn = isFeatureAvailable ? state : false
        })
    }
    
    func ifFeatureAvailable() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class ToggleViewModell: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool
    var action: ((Bool) -> Void)
    
    init(state: Bool, toggleAction: @escaping((Bool) -> Void)) {
        isOn = state
        action = toggleAction
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 view models in the first place? You should not have two sources of truth like this anyway. Can you show why you need to do this? This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Note, for your classes to use `@Published ` you need to have `ObservableObject`, eg `class Coordinator: ObservableObject {...}`

Comment: @Sweeper, I have coordinator that creates viewmodels and pass dependencies. Moreover ToggleViewModel is injected into other view model as [ToggleViewModels] becase there several toggles in the screen and each of them has it's own toggle action

Comment: Maybe use Combine to subscribe to changes?

Comment: I suggest you restructure your code and **do not nest** ObservableObjects.
Note that `ObservableObject` is for use in `Views`, not for use in other classes, meaning `func someMethod() {...}` is close to useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Combine Issue: Sharing Data between ViewModels via AppEventsManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097285/swiftui-combine-issue-sharing-data-between-viewmodels-via-appeventsmanager)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start over, in SwiftUI you are supposed to use a hierarchy of View structs for your view data, not objects. Try declaring @State in a parent View and pass down as a let for read access or or @Binding var for read/write. Use computed var to transform data into child View inits. The idea is that you declare the state high enough so it can be passed down to all the Views that need it. When making a new View first ask yourself what data does it need to do its job?