# How to Achieve a Single Source of Truth with Multiple Subviews and Sub-ViewModels?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I have multiple subviews, each with its own associated ViewModel, and I want to implement a "Single Source of Truth" approach for data management. The goal is to avoid manually syncing data between subviews and the parent view and ensure that changes made in one place are automatically reflected everywhere.

I've considered using `EnvironmentObject` for this purpose, but I'm concerned about the tight coupling it introduces between views and the difficulty it may pose for testing and UI previews.

Is there a recommended approach or best practice for achieving a Single Source of Truth in a scenario like this, where multiple subviews and sub-ViewModels are involved? I'd like to maintain a clean and maintainable codebase while ensuring that data changes are propagated seamlessly throughout the app.

I'm open to any insights, code examples, or design patterns that can help me maintain a clean and efficient codebase while ensuring data changes propagate seamlessly throughout the app.

Thanks for your guidance!

Example mock project:

FormView

```swift
@MainActor class FormViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var firstStepData = FirstStepDataModel()
    var secondStepData = SecondStepDataModel()
}

struct FormView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = FormViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // switch between steps and load data back from model.
            FirstStepView(vm: .init(data: vm.firstStepData)) { data in
                vm.firstStepData = data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FirstStepView

```swift
struct FirstStepDataModel: Codable {
    var personalData = PersonalInformationsDataModel()
    var contactData = ContactInformationsDataModel()
}

@MainActor class FirstStepViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: FirstStepDataModel
    let personalVM: PersonalInformationsViewModel
    let contactVM: ContactInformationsViewModel
    private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    init(data: FirstStepDataModel) {
        self._data = Published(initialValue: data)
        self.personalVM = PersonalInformationsViewModel(data: data.personalData)
        self.contactVM = ContactInformationsViewModel(data: data.contactData)
        syncSubVMs()
    }

    func syncSubVMs() {
        personalVM.$data
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] data in
                self?.data.personalData = data
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        contactVM.$data
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] data in
                self?.data.contactData = data
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

struct FirstStepView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: FirstStepViewModel
    let nextStep: (FirstStepDataModel) -> Void
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PersonalInformationsView(vm: vm.personalVM)
            ContactInformationsView(vm: vm.contactVM)
            Button("Next Step") {
                // go next step
                // send data model to service
                // put step data to FormViewModel's step data.
                nextStep(vm.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CommonViews - These views are common views used in other steps, so I cannot embed them within the view, and these views have their own logic and network requests.

```swift
struct PersonalInformationsDataModel: Codable {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}

@MainActor final class PersonalInformationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: PersonalInformationsDataModel
    init(data: PersonalInformationsDataModel) {
        self._data = Published(initialValue: data)
    }
    // Validations...
    // Network requests...
}

struct PersonalInformationsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: PersonalInformationsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("First Name", text: $vm.data.firstName)
            TextField("Last Name", text: $vm.data.lastName)
        }
    }
}

struct ContactInformationsDataModel: Codable {
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
    var faxNumber: String = ""
}

@MainActor final class ContactInformationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: ContactInformationsDataModel
    init(data: ContactInformationsDataModel) {
        self._data = Published(initialValue: data)
    }
    // Validations...
    // Network requests...
}

struct ContactInformationsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ContactInformationsViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Phone Number", text: $vm.data.phoneNumber)
            TextField("Fax Number", text: $vm.data.faxNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried passing all of them from the parent view with binding, but there were issues with UI updates. Also, it was a bit challenging to bind the variables I hold in the view model back to the view with binding

Comment: One option is to skip the view models for the sub views and use @Binding properties instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson View models are already working well. My problem is syncing data between sub views and parent views. If I use classes instead of structs for data models, I wouldn't encounter any issues. However, in this case, updating the UI becomes challenging.

Comment: I always use classes for both view models and models because you want them to conform to `ObservableObject`. My view models (when I use them) simply expose/update properties from my model and provide abstraction.  The model is always passed to the view model (typically from the view's environment) when the view model is instantiated. Note that what you have named as "models" (e.g. `PersonalInformationsDataModel`) is not a model. It is simply a data type. Your model would hold instances of these.

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually, I just want my subviews to modify my data. However, for example, the contact view also loads the customer's contact information from the service if available, and since I use the contact view in multiple screens, I thought about including this logic within it. What do you think about this: I continue using view models for my container views but remove view models for subviews and place their logic inside the data models and make them observable object?

Comment: No, the data objects should remain as Codable structs. You need an actual model objects or objects. This model object can contain your logic. If you still need view models then these can contain logic for specific views.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Combine Issue: Sharing Data between ViewModels via AppEventsManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097285/swiftui-combine-issue-sharing-data-between-viewmodels-via-appeventsmanager)

Comment: @loremipsum No, as I said I don't want to share single object with all my views. Actually I don't have a big problem. Just don't want to sync my datas manually. Because it's prone to bugs.

Comment: What you are saying doesn’t make sense. “A single source of truth without sharing a single object”. That is an oxymoron it doesn’t matter what approach you use. 1 source == 1 object. There are different flavors of sources but always 1. I can come up with several different approaches but always 1.

Comment: @loremipsum I can pass FormViewModel to all sub views. And every sub view can edit related data in it. But it causes every sub views depended to FormViewModel. I just want to bind related data from FormViewModel. If there is only one sub view it's not a problem I can. But when there is multiple sub views it's getting harder.

Comment: I get what you are saying, look at the sample in the question. ViewModels by definition are not shared, they belong to one view and one view only. You move away shared data down to a manager, that manager now becomes the source of truth that any view model can access... from anywhere.

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` data struct is the view model already and you have to learn `@State` and `@Binding` to use it successfully. If you try to reimplement this in objects you'll have major problems. `@StateObject` is designed for Combine async pipelines, it's totally misusing it to try to reimplement View struct/State/Binding.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass the entire viewmodel into the subviews. Importantly:
The root view must have the viewmodel marked as `@StateObject`, and the child views must have it marked as `@ObservedObject`